# External Image loads on ListView intermittently

Tags: java, php, android

I am using Volley trying to populate my ListView with data from an external server. I am retrieiving an image and a String for each line on the ListView.

For testing, all I have is 3 sets of image and String which would appear on the ListView as follows:

[image]

Problem is this doesn't always load. Sometimes its instant. Otherwise, it never loads even if I wait 5 minutes. Average it loads fine about 1 out of 5 tries. I am using Volley and believe it runs on its own thread thus no interference. I don't see any Exceptions. It just gets stuck and never loads image and text.

I am holding the URL to the location of the images and pointing to that location to obtain the image. For example pointing to this a URL:

```
https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-512.png
```

Passing in the URL on a browser instantly retrieves the image instantly. I have tried to load only the String without the images. (ie: item 1, item 2, item 3). That always works but even then, that takes about 5 seconds.

Am I fetching the information wrong? Is there anyway I can optimise it? Even insanely large applications are fetching data in a couple of seconds. This is plain ridiculous for a test data of 3 images and 3 text. Please advice.

Since I am loading data on the ListView on the fly, I am using a CustomAdapter class as follows:

**CustomProductListAdapter class**

```
public class CustomProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private ArrayList < String > productNames = new ArrayList < >();
    private ArrayList < String > productImages = new ArrayList < >();
    private Context context;

    public CustomProductListAdapter(ArrayList < String > productNames, ArrayList < String > productImages, Context context) {
        this.productNames = productNames;
        this.productImages = productImages;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return productNames.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_product_list_layout, null);
        }

        final TextView listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);

        String productTitle = productNames.get(position);
        if (productNames.get(position).length() > 25) productTitle = productTitle.substring(0, 22) + "...";
        listItemText.setText(productTitle);

        final ImageView productImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.productImgView);

        Picasso.with(context).load(productImages.get(position)).into(productImg);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is Activity where I am loading and displaying the above image using Volley

**ViewProductActivity Class**

```
public class ViewProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView productListView;
    String title = "exampleTitle";

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    StringRequest request;
    final String PRODUCT_URL = "http://www.example.com/app/product.php";

    ArrayList < String > products,
    images;
    CustomProductListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_product);

        productListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productListView);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        products = new ArrayList < >();
        images = new ArrayList < >();

        getProducts();
    }

    void getProducts() {
        request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, PRODUCT_URL, new Response.Listener < String > () {@Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String viewName = jsonObject.getString("viewName");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(viewName);

                    for (int x = 0; x < jsonArray.length(); x++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);
                        products.add(jsonPart.getString("name"));
                        images.add(jsonPart.getString("img"));
                    }

                    adapter = new CustomProductListAdapter(products, images, ViewProductActivity.this);
                    productListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {@Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {@Override
            protected Map < String,
            String > getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                HashMap < String,
                String > hashMap = new HashMap < >();
                hashMap.put("name", title);
                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

This is PHP script which queries the database and returns JSON

**product.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    $json['failed'] = "Connection fail";
    echo json_encode($json);
}

$name = $_POST['name'];

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "SELECT name, img FROM table_name WHERE category = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting");

//create an array
$emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}

//echo json_encode($emparray);
echo json_encode(array('viewName' => $emparray));

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($con);
```